# Binding images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to show multiple image on a uniform grid that i'm getting their urls from the internet).When i execute the code the images are not displayed.
This is the videos window:

```xml
<Window x:Name="videos" x:Class="Navigateur.Presentation.Videos"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Navigateur.Presentation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="207" Width="463" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized">

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Margin="72,30,76,30" ItemsSource="{Binding images}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Navigateur.Presentation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Videos : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Image> images;
        public Videos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public ObservableCollection<Image> Images()
        {
            images = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
            ServiceReferenceVideo.VideoServiceClient wcf = new ServiceReferenceVideo.VideoServiceClient();
            foreach (var item in wcf.GetAllVideos())
            {
                string link_thumb = wcf.GetThumbImage((wcf.GetVideoId(item.urlVideo)));
                var wSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(link_thumb));
                var wImage = new Image { Source = wSource };
                images.Add(wImage);
            }
            return images;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few issues here:

- Your list (`ItemsControl`) accesses the images via a `Binding`, but you never set the list's `DataContext` - the object which the binding system will try to get data from (in your case, the `Videos` window itself).
- Bindings only work on **public properties**, not private fields like your `images` collection.
- When the `Images()` function is done loading thumbnails, the binding system needs to be notified that the bound collection (**public property**) has changed, either by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raising the `PropertyChanged` event, or by making the property a `DependencyProperty`.
- The way it's written now, the `Images()` function creates a collection of `Image`s, and the ItemsControl uses them as the sources for new `Image`s. Using an `Image` as the source of an `Image` is overkill (if it even works). An `Image` happliy takes e.g. a URI as a source though, so instead of generating `Image`s in code, your `images` collection can simply be the list of `link_thumb` urls.

I suggest you read up on data binding in WPF. There are lots of resources out there.

For this particular case though, because everything is done in your `Videos` window, you could skip bindings altogether, and just force-feed the list of images into the `ItemsControl` if you give it a name:

```
<ItemsControl Margin="72,30,76,30" x:Name="_imageList" >
    ...
```

Code-behind:

```
public void Images()
{
    var images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    var wcf = new ServiceReferenceVideo.VideoServiceClient();
    foreach (var item in wcf.GetAllVideos())
    {
        string link_thumb = wcf.GetThumbImage((wcf.GetVideoId(item.urlVideo)));
        images.Add(link_thumb);
    }

    _imageList.ItemsSource = images;
}
```

Comment: well i removed the Images() function and i placed the above code in the Videos constructor and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank You @Sphinxxx you save me a lot of time.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! If it didn't work the first time, maybe you never actually called the `Images()` function?

Comment: it is exactly what you said..I called the Images() in the constructor and everything is ok. Thank you again